# How to make a fuse-filesystem appear on /media/$USER without root or changing fstab?

Tags: fuse, udisks

I'm a bit perplexed about this. I'm sure that we're 'supposed' to use udisks or udisksctl to mount things on that place, where they'll be picked up by nautilus etc.

However, how can i do that for something which isn't a classical filesystem? Ie i installed unionfs-fuse, mount a copy-on-write filesystem like so:

`unionfs-fuse -ocow "$somedir=RW:$anotherdir=RO" "$mountpoint"`

In there, the mount-point has to be a directory, but it obviously can't be on /media/$user since that is a root dir. And udisks can't do it either since it has no option to delegate to unionfs-fuse and has no option to bind mount (not that i would want it).

There is no solution to this except dump the mount point on the documents or the user folder?

Comment: maybe if you add a directory like e.g. `mkdir /media/blabla`  and give yourself all rights on that directory (for this you need root permissions ofcourse). Than you can use `media/blabla/$user`

Comment: That's what i'm trying to avoid, needing permissions, while still seeing the mount on nautilus. But!!! i just found out it happens anyway. FUSE makes nautilus see the mount whereever it actually happens, so this topic is unnecessary (except maybe if someone wants to answer it for fun).

Comment: well then you can choose between a) delete your question or b) answer your own question and accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that although it's not possible to make udisksctl explicitly recognize a mount, it happens anyway, making nautilus recognize it, *if you mounted on a visible user folder*

My whole problem was that my previous attempt was on .cache/ before i tried to change it to /media/$USER and hitting this. I tried it on $HOME/Desktop later and it appears on nautilus. So it works.